# How to print a line number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, whitespace

I'm trying to go through a file to check every line with what white space it starts. we want to use space as a start or a tab. If one line starts with space and another line with tab I want to inform the user that the white spaces are not consistent. And an example I want to print one line that starts with space and one line that starts with tab. And Im stuck at the getting the line number part. I tried file.gets to get the first white space but it isnt working for me(so I didnt include it in my code below). Help how do I print the line number.

```
tabs = spaces = false

file = File.read("file_name")
file.each do |line|

  line =~ /^\t/ and tabs = true
  line =~ /^ / and spaces = true    

  if spaces and tabs
    puts  "The white spaces at the beginning of each line are not consistent.\n"
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for proper use of control flow operations.

Comment: @engineersmnky: This is a perlism, I think. I never see this in ruby. It's usually `tabs = true if line =~ /^\t/`

Comment: Perl was part of Ruby's inspiration so the purpose of the operators was almost certainly for exactly the situation above. I'm seeing `and` and `or` being use for control flow by experts in Ruby more and more these days, although I also see their use being banned or discouraged in style guides. The question I ask is: "Does 'and' or 'or' give me anything that I couldn't get from the more readable 'if' or 'unless'? To me it seems that the latter is usually more in the spirit of Ruby, being closer to natural English. (Is there a Ruby equivalent of the word 'Pythonic'?)

Comment: @AFaderDarkly: ruby-esque :)

Comment: @AFaderDarkly [Here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) is a great post on the subject.

Comment: Indeed, that blog helped me form my opinions of these operators. Also this: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide and this: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby may reflect the Ruby community general view a little, perhaps... But again I say the bottom line is code readability. Some examples in the blog post are pleasant and easy to read, if a little weird from the perspective of natural English, but things can get opaque or confusing if you overuse them.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `file.lineno` to get the number of the current line you are reading in the file.

```
file = File.open("file_name")
file.each do |line|
  ...
  puts "#{file.lineno}: #{line}" # Outputs the line number and the content of the line
end
```

Comment: `File.read('xx')` reads the whole file in as a string. `each` and `lineno` will then fail. Probably a typo. ;)

Comment: More of an oversight than a typo, but thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 4):

Based on @zajn's answer:

```
file = File.open("filename.txt")
file.each do |line|
  puts "#{file.lineno}: #{line}"
end
```

Or you could use 'each with index':

```
File.open("another_file.txt").each_with_index do |line,i|
  puts "#{i}: #{line}"
end
```

which looks a touch less magical.

Comment: `each_with_index` will also be 0-based where `lineno` is 1-based.